# ¿Como puedo poner writelines(struct.unpack('=2B2I'), msg)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quería saber cómo puedo poner:

```
 f.writelines(struct.unpack('=2B2I', msg))
```

Es que me da un error en esa linea:

> `write()` argument must be str, not int.

Quiero poder desempaquetar un paquete en un servidor.
Lo que quiero que haga el servidor es que cuando le llegue el fichero f desde el cliente lo desempaquete. El fichero tiene bytes y quiero que el servidor lo desempaquete tal cual le ha llegado.

Comment: Se entiende que `msg` contiene una cadena de 10 bytes en la cual hay 2 bytes y 2 enteros (de 4 bytes). Mediante `unpack` extraes de esa secuencia de bytes los valores concretos, y en este caso tendrías como resultado una tupla de cuatro elementos, los dos primeros serían los 2 bytes iniciales y los dos siguientes los 2 enteros. Le pasas esa tupla a `writelines()` y de ahí el error, ya que `writelines()` espera cadenas. ¿Qué es lo que querías realmente volcar a fichero? ¿La representación ASCII de esos números? ¿Separados por espacios, comas...?

Comment: Por otro lado, yo cambiaría el `=` por `>` o `<` según corresponda, ya que si los datos te han llegado de la red no tienes por qué asumir que la _endianity_ con la que vienen sea la misma que la que usa la máquina que los recibe (que es lo que significa el `=` inicial)

Comment: Hola @abulafia , lo que quiero es que pueda desempaquetar el fichero que contiene x bytes, pero no se si es como lo he puesto. El fichero le llega desde un cliente.

Comment: No entiendo nada. ¿Desempaquetar un fichero? ¿Qué formato tiene la transmisión? ¿Algún tipo de cabecera? ¿De dónde sacaste lo de `=2B2I`?

Comment: Es un trabajo que tengo que hacer, tengo que hacer un servidor y un cliente con TFTP sobre UDP, me pide que cliente envié una petición RRQ, WRQ o QUIT y que el servidor le conteste. Se hace con modo netascii, y el paquete sería : 2 bytes     string    1 byte     string   1 byte
           | Opcode |  Filename  |   0  |    Mode    |   0  |
Lo que he puesto aquí es una prueba de desempaquetado, porque no se como hacer los paquetes tanto del emisor como del receptor. Siento si te he hecho un lío. @abulafia

Comment: Por tanto se trata de un trabajo de clase. No sé hasta qué punto tienes una duda concreta o más bien no sabes por dónde empezar ¿Tienes claro cómo va el protocolo TFTP? ¿Usas el RFC-1350 o algún otro tipo de documentación para saber el formato de los paquetes? ¿Sabes qué hace exactamente `unpack()`? Te recomendaría estudiar estos temas y el [código de tftpy](https://github.com/msoulier/tftpy) para ir entendiéndolo. No podemos darte en una respuesta aquí una implementación completa de TFTP.

Comment: Sí uso RFC 1350, unpack convierte una secuencia
de bytes a datos nativos de Python. Se que no puedo pedir eso, es mi trabajo por lo tanto lo tengo que hacer yo, pero el caso es que no se como hacer los paquetes que me piden y más porque no he dado nunca python. Estoy mirando el código que me dices, pero no comprendo los paquetes. Gracias de todas formas @abulafia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedo dar aquí una implementación del protocolo TFTP, pero voy a intentar ayudarte explicándote someramente qué es eso de un "paquete" y cómo funciona `unpack()`.

El protocolo TFTP transmite mediante UDP bloques de bytes llamados "datagramas", que tienen una estructura interna descrita en el [RFC-1350](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1350). Por ejemplo, uno de estos bloques es el paquete RRQ/WRQ (petición de lectura/escritura), que según el RFC tiene este formato:

```
 2 bytes     string    1 byte     string   1 byte
 ------------------------------------------------
| Opcode |  Filename  |   0  |    Mode    |   0  |
 ------------------------------------------------
```

Los dos primeros bytes transportan un `short int`, en orden de red (big endian). El valor de este entero nos dice si la operación es `RRQ` (valdría 1) o `WRQ` (valdría 2). Necesitamos extraer también el nombre de fichero, que es una cadena ASCII cuya longitud no sabemos de antemano sino que debemos iterar hasta encontrar el 0 que la termina, y el modo, que es otra cadena similar a la anterior.

Para extraer el entero inicial (Opcode) podemos usar `.unpack("!H", buffer[:2])`. Mediante la cadena "!H" le decimos que se trata de un `short int` (eso significa H) en orden de red (eso significa la admiración).

Para extraer el nombre de fichero o el modo, en cambio, no podemos usar `unpack()`,  porque a `unpack()` hay que pasarle qué tamaño en bytes tiene cada campo que  queramos extraer, y aquí no sabemos el tamaño de las cadenas que representan el nombre de fichero y el modo.

El siguiente código puede servir entonces para extraer la información buscada:

```
# En la variable datagrama tenemos el paquete recibido
opcode = struct.unpack("!H", datagrama[:2])

if opcode == 2:
    i=2
    filename = ""
    while ord(datagrama[i]) != 0:
        filename += chr(datagrama[i])
        i += 1
    mode = ""
    i += 1
    while ord(datagrama[i]) != 0:
        mode += chr(datagrama[i])
        i += 1
```

El código es feo y sucio, y no puedo probarlo, pero creo que funcionará. Básicamente va iterando sobre el datagrama mirando si encuentra un byte de valor 0 y mientras no lo encuentre lo va copiando a la variable de tipo string apropiada.

Al terminar estos bucles `filename` y `mode` tendrán los valores extraidos del paquete (si el opcode era 2). `mode` valdrá por ejemplo "netascii", que indica cómo hay que interpretar otros paquetes.

Pero este no es el único tipo de paquete que puedes recibir. De hecho, este paquete no contiene el fichero en sí, sino sólo su nombre. Paquetes posteriores de tipo "DATA" serán los que tengan los contenidos del fichero.

Un paquete de tipo DATA tiene esta otra estructura, según el RFC:

```
  2 bytes     2 bytes      n bytes
 ----------------------------------
| Opcode |   Block #  |   Data     |
 ----------------------------------
```

En este caso el "Opcode" se extraería como antes, y su valor sería 3. El "Block #" es otro entero short que contiene el número de bloque (los bloques vienen numerados y tu código debería guardarlos en el orden correcto indicado por ese número). El resto del paquete son datos. Si son exactamente 512 bytes, es que después vendrán más datagramas, es decir, el fichero no se ha acabado. Si son menos de 512 es el último paquete de ese fichero.

Podríamos extraer esa información así, por ejemplo:

```
opcode = struct.unpack("!H", datagrama[:2])
if opcode == 3:
    block_num = struct.unpack("!H", datagrama[2:4])
    data = datagrama[4:]  # resto del paquete
```

Ahora bien, esto estaría formando parte de algún tipo de bucle que vaya recibiendo paquetes uno tras otro. Cada paquete se decodificaría de este modo, y se usaría el `block_num` para ir guardándolo en alguna estructura que después permita reconstruir la secuencia. Por ejemplo, se podría usar un diccionario cuya clave fuese `block_num` y el valor fuese `data`.

Al recibir un paquete con `len(data)<512` sabríamos que habíamos recibido el último. Entonces se podría usar el diccionario para ver si están todas las claves e iterar sobre esas claves por orden para ir generando la secuencia de bytes que podría ir a fichero.

Pero aún faltaría por implementar los ACK, y muchas más cosas...

Francamente, me parece una tarea muy compleja para alguien que acaba de empezar con python. Aquí hay de todo, sockets, UDP, formatos binarios, ficheros, ... Espero que con lo que aquí te he contado tengas para ir "tirando del hilo".